# How to transfer memory stream object through Sharp SSH library?

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

I am creating a memory stream on run time

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream); 
        writer.WriteLine("There could by any text over here....");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
```

Now i want to transfer this memory stream via SSH library to a remote SFTP server and want to save it on that SFTP server.

I have tried following code but its not working

```
     using (var scp = new ScpClient("HostName", "test", "test"))
        {
            scp.Connect();
            scp.Upload(stream, "/Files/Test/temp.txt");
            scp.Disconnect();
        }
```

it get stuck forever on following line without any error

```
scp.Upload(stream, "/Files/Test/temp.txt");
```

Can any one please help?

Comment: Can you add some Details on "is not working"? Do you get an error?

Comment: I have edited the description. please read the last couple of lines

Answer (score 0):

Use `SftpClient.UploadFile` instead of `ScpClient.Upload`.

If that doesn't help, make sure your firewall is set up properly. It's very helpful to use a tool such as WireShark to monitor the communication in case there's some weird error (it also enables you to easily see authentication errors etc.).